# How to set replica count for EKS addon deployments?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have replaced the `ebs-csi-controller` installation with the AWS provided `ebs-csi` add-on. Everything is well and good but it creates `2` pods by default which I can scale it to `1` after the installation.

I want to avoid the need to do this scaling manually and set the replica count to `1` in the installation phase itself.
I couldn't locate/find a documentation that tells me how to acheive this.

How do I set the replica count during installation?

Answer (score 1):

If you run `aws eks describe-addon-configuration` it will output the json schema for the addon. If `replicas` is part of the schema, you will be able to set the number of replicas for the addon, otherwise you won't. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/eks/describe-addon-configuration.html.